# Precise matrix inversion in Q

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, symbolic-math, markov-chains, matrix-inverse

Given an invertible matrix M over the rationals Q, the inverse matrix M^(-1) is again a matrix over Q. Are their (efficient) libraries to compute the inverse precisely?

I am aware of high-performance linear algebra libraries such as BLAS/LAPACK, but these libraries are based on floating point arithmetic and are thus not suitable for computing precise (analytical) solutions.

**Motivation**: I want to compute the absorption probabilities of a large [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) using its [fundamental matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Fundamental_matrix). I would like to do so precisely.

**Details**: By large, I mean a 1000x1000 matrix in the best case, and a several million dimensional matrix in the worst case. The further I can scale things the better. (I realize that the worst case is likely far out of reach.)

Comment: If you wind up writing this yourself, see https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/ for helpful tips on how to perform the calculations efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Eigen matrix library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org), which with little effort works on arbitrary scalar types. There is an example in the documentation how to use it with [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)s `mpq_class`: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html

Of course, as @btilly noted, most of the time you should not calculate the inverse, but calculate a matrix decomposition and use that to solve equation systems. For rational numbers you can use any LU-decomposition, or if the matrix is symmetric, the LDLt decomposition. See here for a [catalogue of decompositions](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html).